# Is it possible to know what is the dielectric voltage between earth and conductor of those cables?

Tags: cables, cable-assemblies

I am looking to know what is the maximum voltage (dielectric voltage) that it can be applied between the conductors of the cable and the earth (not into the cable). Usually I look for a term which is called " Voltage Test " but in the datasheet below I am not able to find the informations :

https://fr.farnell.com/amphenol-ltw/hmc-05bffm-sl8a01/nmea-micro-c-5pin-f-conn-f-pin/dp/2912028
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Phoenix%20Contact%20PDFs/1669770.pdf

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: Rated 60V in spec

Comment: I m looking for the dielectric voltage. I do not think that 60 V could make an arc into the cable or outside the cable ?

Comment: dielectric voltage : for a pure electrically insulating material, the maximum electric field that the material can withstand under ideal conditions without undergoing electrical breakdown and becoming electrically conductive (i.e. without failure of its insulating properties).

Comment: Try and find the connector used in the wiring assembly and examine the data sheet for just the connector and see what it reveals about the dielectric withstand voltage. Step and repeat for the cable type used.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dielectric breakdown of plastic is > 5kV/mm but surface contam. may reduce that to 50V/mm depending...on extreme humidity and dust, normally 500V/mm

Impulse ratings <1us may be 10 x higher

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd datasheet (and the first one also) have something like:

[image: Datasheet Image]

I would take that as the maximum voltage to apply to the thing either conductor-to-conductor or conductor-to-ground.

Answer (score 0):

The rating of the cable is “low” at 60V and that is the maximum you should be willing to apply. Sure the cable won’t breakdown through the outer jacket at 120V, but remember that when the cable gets hot things change and there’s increased leakage through insulation, the insulation may wear quicker due to mechanical friction, and so on. The manufacturer didn’t want to spend the effort to qualify it for anything more, and that’s reasonable, since it’s an uncommon requirement.

So, if you want a cable that can withstand 1kV from conductor to jacket surface, guaranteed in the specified temperature and applications, then you need a cable with a 1kV spec for that voltage. Usually that will be custom because it will have two very different ratings: one for conductor-to-conductor voltage, another for conductor-to-jacket voltage.

If I had an application like that, I’d qualify an existing cable myself and buy enough of it to last the production run, since it’d necessarily be a low-volume application. You also **absolutely must talk to the applications engineer at the cable manufacturer**. You obviously have a specific and critical (it seems) requirement, and without getting the cable vendor into the loop, you’ll be taking on a lot of unnecessary risk.